# Visual Studi 2015 C++ wrong debug variable and wrong disassembly code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

Problem: A MFC application where in some part of the code some member variables of the main app (theApp) are not accessed at the correct position.
Pseudo code:
The main app has a lot of member classes

class CMarcaApp : public CWinAppEx{
....
public:

CMyClass1 m_class1;
CMyClass2 m_class2;
...
...
StepRepeat m_steprepeat;
....

StepRepeat is a simply class with some variables.

A lot of dialog classes also exist in this application. Some of them are opened according mouse events e.g. in the mainframe class.

```
Mainframe::Onclicked(){
 CMyDialog dlg;
 dlg.DoModal();
}
```

The thing is that, opening a certain dialog (that is not much different than any other dialog), and accessing a member variable of "theApp" (either via AfxGetApp() or theApp as an external global variable), the contents of variables of this class member are no longer correct. I found out the "pointer" to this class variable is no longer correct. In other words:

```
   &(theApp->m_steprepeat) is no longer pointing to the correct place.
```

This is absolutely annoying. I can see in the dissambly code that the disassembled code is simply wrong by adding the wrong offset to the (theApp)'s pointer when trying to access m_class2.

I have seen that in the Debug window the members of m_class2 didn't make any sense, so I created a global variable StepRepeat *theSteprepeat;

In Initinstance() this pointer is intialized to
theSteprepeat= &(theApp->m_steprepeat)

From everywhere I can access 'theSteprepeat' and its member variables and everything looks fine, but in some scopes (e.g. inside some OnInitDialog() function), the direction &(theApp->m_steprepat) does not match "theSteprepeat".

In the disassembly code I can see that the "offset" is really wrong, depending on "where" I access this variables.
Here you can see the disassembled codes for the "same C++" code and how it is different in both cases.

Correct disassembled code:  called somewhere inside the app

```
 5460:  StepRepeat *ps = &(app->m_steprepeat);
  008A7FE0 8B 45 E0             mov         eax,dword ptr [app]  
 008A7FE3 05 CC 43 02 00       add         eax,243CCh  
 008A7FE8 89 45 BC             mov         dword ptr [ps],eax
```

Wrong disassembled code:  called somewhere else inside the app

```
 67:    StepRepeat *ps = &(app->m_steprepeat);
 00AFB836 8B 45 E0             mov         eax,dword ptr [app]  
 00AFB839 05 3C 43 02 00       add         eax,2433Ch  
 00AFB83E 89 45 BC             mov         dword ptr [ps],eax
```

As you can see the Offset is different in both disassembled codes. 243CCh in the first code, 2433Ch in the second code case. 'app' is a local pointer to 'theApp' or AfxGetApp() (in both cases the same thing happens). The code StepRepeat *ps = &(app->m_steprepeat) is an add for debug purposes as I got crazy to find out what happens.

This problem is not limited to the 'StepRepeat' member, but also applies to "CMyClass2 or some other members). The CMarcaApp class has a lot of members and this problems seems to occur only for members that are declared near to the end of the class definition. If I move them to the beginning, the problem does not occure, although I think that the problem just has shifted to some other members (that I did not inspect).

Any hints what this can be ?

Comment: This looks like you either have multiple definitions of the `app` class (which are different sizes), or you made changes to the class and not everything that uses it was recompiled.

Comment: A second option to a mismatch between sizes is mixing debug and release. Meaning linking a debug library to a release application or viseversa

Comment: It sounds as if your architecture is a bit off. Could you draw your classes and how they interact with each other? E.g. in your OnClicked method the "normal" way would be to pass a `this` pointer to the dialog CMyDialog dlg(this) and in that way be able to set any values when user presses OK in the dialog and not via some global variable

Comment: This can happen when you use C-style casts in class hierarchies. The compiler trusts you, and calculates offsets based on the type information provided. If that type information isn't correct, the offsets start to look wrong.

Comment: Do this. At every step along the way, log/print the value of `sizeof(app)` both outside the class as well as `sizeof(*this)` within the class methods. Somewhere there will be a mismatch between the sizes. This sort of thing happens when you have different preprocessor defines between the .h and the .cpp file.   Can also happen when you add\remove a member variable but forget to "build clean" (recompile and relink everything).  Can also happen when you do a cast incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys for your recommendations. I finally found out what it was. I have  a one and only `"defines.h"` file where I sometimes add some new defines for new features. In the code than the typical `#ifdef SUPPORT_FEATURE #endif` stuff.

In one of the dialog files I forgot to include this `"defines.h"`. Thus, the app-class in this compiled module had a "smaller" size than everywhere else.

Would be good to include a "symbols-size" check in the VS -Debugger to be able to find such inconsistencies. It got me crazy during 2 days doubting in everything.

Comment: If you are using precompiled headers, you can include your `"defines.h"` in stdafx.h and then forget about it.

Comment: This should have failed to compile when done properly. C++' type system is the perfect tool to encode compile-time decisions, making them subject to the compiler's verification. The preprocessor, on the other hand, is the most silent footgun you'll find.